# How to locate timer channels for this uC board?

Tags: microcontroller, timer

I'm trying to visualize and point on diagram where timer channels at this [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/dm00037051.pdf).

STM32 uses the term channels. I guess what mean by timer channels are timer outputs. What is meant by channel?

Can someone show an example for this board for ChannelX of TimerX on the manual or datasheet?

Comment: Have you looked at section 2.2.21, Timers and watchdogs?

Comment: I mean on diagram how can we route a timer to a channel? Is it numbered on diagrams?

Comment: The timers already have the channels. A single timer may have multiple channels for input or output. Read the MCU reference manual.

Comment: Channel means an independent path/set of registers for a specific functionality. You better search for a programming/reference manual rather than datasheet, which is not very helpful.

Comment: The pin PD15 is assigned to TIM4_CH4. But where is that TIM4_CH4 on the diagram? Can we point it?

Comment: Is a channel a piece of wire at the output of a timer you mean?

Comment: I thought channel is the output but you saying its a register.

Comment: search for `TIM4` in the document ... the first instance shows the TIM4 register ... it feeds 4 channels ... each channel is `input capture/output compare` ... each channel is a pin ... I am not clear what that means at this time

Comment: Ah so 4 channels means here 4 possible I/O pins correct?

Comment: Pin might be an endpoint of a channel. A channel is whole set of logic providing the functionality. You can see from the description of the pinouts, that the same pin can be multiplexed to different channels (see page 49, pin PA2 for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A timer has a counter running off a clock (which may go through a pre-divider first).

A channel for that timer is centered around a register containing a compare output or capture input value for use with that counter. There may be more than one channel for a timer/counter.

The input pin for the capture input or the output pin for the compare output (depending on what mode you are running) can be connected to a number of pre-defined pins using the IO configuration registers to set alternate functions.

The [STM32 User Reference Manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0090-stm32f405415-stm32f407417-stm32f427437-and-stm32f429439-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) is much more enlightening than the datasheet. That's the one what tells you how to actually use the devices in a product family. It tells you how the peripherals work and what registers you need to configure. The STM32 datasheets, for the most part, are only useful for information that is not common to the MCU family such as the pinouts for a specific package that an MCU comes in.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [cube MX tool](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubemx.html) to configure timers, attach them to GPIO's and many other things. It will generate code that you can use in your project.